# Display HTML content web notification in chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing one chrome plugin for my web application.

In this plugin I need to display web notification into other website pages in the right side bottom of the page.

So in this web notification I want to display html script inside of the notification using JQuery. I tried like below code.

```
    var jsonarray = JSON.parse(res);
    var htmlData = '';

jQuery.each(jsonarray, function(v) {

    name    = jsonarray['name'];
    img = jsonarray['img'];
    pageurl = jsonarray['pageurl'];

    Adata = '<div class="wtb-popup-opt" style="background-color: red;">'+
                '<a class="wtb_popup_pd_plink" href="'+pageurl+'" target="_blank">'+
                '<div class="wtb-popup-opt-pd wtb-popup-opt-o" wtb-tn="first">'+name+'</div>'+
                '</a>'
             '</div>';
    htmlData    =   htmlData+Adata;

});
var title = 'Similar Products';  
new Notification(title, {
    icon: 'icon.png',
    body: htmlData
  });
```

In the above code **htmlData** is html div content. I want to make display this html content into web notification.

Can anyone help me to display like html page into notification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use html based notification as it's been [deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications). However you can use [rich notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications).